# Extra pieces in 76112 Batmobile

Tags: building, powered-up

I've been building the new app-controlled Batmobile. As far as I can tell, step 34 shows many more elements in the parts list than are actually used in the build. What is going on here?

[image: step 34]

Comment: There's also only 3 `1x` markings, so I think it must be a mistake.

Comment: I should also mention that this isn't just a simple misprint. I have all of these elements left after completing the build.

Comment: Wish to comment that I think this is my favorite set this year ;)

Comment: It's a great set. I love that the hub light shines through the red cockpit element. That makes it look great in low light without needing to include the powered headlight element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are in a perforated bag and the entire contents of the bag is listed. You only need some of them in this step and in a few steps later on. I think such bag is called an "accessory" bag and it is common to have the instructions like this for such bag. The first set that comes to mind that did the same was the
Big Ben 10253 where on step 269 on page 187 the entire contents of the bag with minifig tools is listed while you only need 4 times 2 pieces to build the clock arrows.

[image: Big Ben]

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. Thank you! This seems like it may be a holdover from when these elements came still connected to their sprue.